# Getting a property value out of a dictionary using KVC

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I have ten UIImageViews that are badges for a game in my "GoalsViewController" class they are set to hidden = YES; in Interface Builder.

I want to make them hidden = NO; when certain levels are reached in my "GameViewController" class.

I am stuck because I am not sure if the solution I have is even going to work.

What I have so far is:

In **GoalsVC.h** I have a

```
NSMutableDictionary *goalsDictionary;
```

and a getter method that returns goalsDictionary

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)goalsDictionary;
```

Then in **GoalsVC.m** I alloc and init the goalsDictionary

```
goalsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
```

I create an imageView

```
UIImageView *goalImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init]; 

goalImage.hidden = YES; 

[goalsDictionary setValue:goalImage forKey:@"PassedLevelOne"];
```

I repeat this same method call nine more times changing the key to different levels.

And it's now that I realize I can't get a property such as hidden from a dictionary can I? The method `setValue:` takes an object and the `forKey:` takes a string.

So is there a better way to tell GoalsViewController to set the hidden property to NO when something in my GameControllerView happens?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand you correctly but is this what you are looking for?

```
UIImageView *passedLevelOneImageView = (UIImageView *)[goalsDictionary objectForKey:@"PassedLevelOne"];
passedLevelOneImageView.hidden = NO;
```

If not let me know and I can try again.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can get a property of an object that is a value in a dictionary. You can use `valueForKeyPath:` method, like this:

```
id myProperty = [goalsDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"PassedLevelOne.hidden"];
```

PS. Of course in the case where the property is a primitive like `BOOL` you can cast the result and assign the value accordingly.